# How do I correct a removeChild error when using FilePond with React

Tags: filepond

I have an implementation of FilePond like this:

```
          <FilePond
            acceptedFileTypes={validMimeTypes}
            allowBrowse={true}
            allowDrop={false}
            allowFileSizeValidation={true}
            allowFileTypeValidation={true}
            allowMultiple={true}
            allowPaste={false} 
            allowRevert={false}
            chunkForce={true}
            chunkSize={5000000}
            chunkUploads={true}
            disabled={false}
            dropValidation={false}
            files={files}
            // File size validation config
            fileSizeBase={1024}
            fileValidateTypeDetectType={
              utilityFunctions.fileValidateTypeDetectType
            }
            fileValidateTypeLabelExpectedTypes={
              messages.FILE_UPLOAD_FILE_TYPE_INVALID
            }
            fileValidateTypeLabelExpectedTypesMap={{}}
            instantUpload={false}
            labelFileTypeNotAllowed={
              messages.FILE_UPLOAD_FILE_TYPE_INVALID_LABEL
            }
            labelMaxFileSize={messages.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE.replace(
              ":maxFileSize",
              utilityFunctions.formatFileSize(maxFileSize)
            )}
            labelMaxFileSizeExceeded={
              messages.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED
            }
            labelMaxTotalFileSize={messages.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_TOTAL_FILE_SIZE.replace(
              ":maxFileSize",
              utilityFunctions.formatFileSize(maxTotalFileSizeInBytes)
            )}
            labelMaxTotalFileSizeExceeded={
              messages.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_TOTAL_FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED
            }
            maxFiles={maxFileCount}
            maxFileSize={maxFileSizeInBytes}
            maxParallelUploads={10}
            maxTotalFileSize={maxTotalFileSizeInBytes}
            name={name}
            onerror={handleFileError}
            onprocessfileprogress={handleProgress}
            onupdatefiles={handleUpdateFiles}
            ref={filePondRef}
            server={server}
          />
```

I keep getting the following on initial load.  Sometime I can get the component to load, but the removeChild error happens anytime you delete a file listed in the filepond.  (It removes the file successfully but throws that error, i.e., clear the error and everything works fine.).

ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')
at Object.DID_REMOVE_ITEM (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66827:38)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63165:37
at Array.forEach ()
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63164:22
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:62974:32
at Array.forEach ()
at Object.j [as _write] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:62973:32)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:62986:27
at Array.forEach ()
at Object.j [as _write] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:62985:26)
at Object._write (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67610:54)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68070:28
at Array.forEach ()
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68069:25
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63145:28
at Array.forEach ()
at e (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63144:33)

The removeChild method is within FilePond, so I am unsure where my error is coming from